# Spark Window Function top N items performance issues

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to get the top n items in a dataset .

Initially I did this.

```
var  df  = Seq( (1 , "row1") , (2,"row2"), (1,"row11")  , (1 , null) ).toDF()

df=df.select($"_1".alias("p_int"), $"_2".alias("p_string"))

val resultDf =df.where($"p_string".isNotNull).select( $"p_int" ,$"p_int" +1  , upper($"p_string") , rank().over(Window.partitionBy($"p_int").orderBy( $"p_string" )) as  "RANKINDEX", row_number().over(Window.partitionBy($"p_int").orderBy( $"p_string" )) as "ROWNUMBER" ).where($"ROWNUMBER" <=  2 )
```

But I want to avoid the performance cost of the operation "where($"ROWNUMBER" <=  10 )"

So I decided to do the following

```
var  df  = Seq( (1 , "row1") , (2,"row2"), (1,"row11")  , (1 , null) ).toDF()

df=df.select($"_1".alias("p_int"), $"_2".alias("p_string"))

val test =df.where($"p_string".isNotNull).select( $"p_int" ,$"p_int" +1  , upper($"p_string") , rank().over(Window.partitionBy($"p_int").orderBy( $"p_string" )) as  "RANKINDEX", row_number().over(Window.partitionBy($"p_int").orderBy( $"p_string" )) as "ROWNUMBER" )

implicit val encoder = RowEncoder(test.schema)

var  temp =test.mapPartitions( _.take(2))
```

However , my testing seems to show that this will not produce the correct output .

Any thoughts why .  Wouldn't the take function on the iterator obtained from the window dataset get the first n elements in the iterator?

Answer (score 0):

Partitions of the `Dataset` don't have have one-to-one correspondence with `PARTITION BY` clause. All the magic in `OVER (PARTITION BY ...)` happens on the much lower level and a single physical partition will process multiple ids.

Also you don't really save the work. To correctly generates `row_numbers` Spark will have to shuffle, sort and scan all the data. You'll need much lower level mechanisms to avoid full shuffle and sort (for example `Aggregator`  with binary heap).